# What does "I would not put a thief in my mouth to steal my brains" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, literature

I just want to ask you a question that I stated above at my title section... What does '*I would not put a thief in my mouth to steal my brains*' mean?

It's a quote from a book called *[True Grit](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=As-3gDwNNPwC&pg=PT13&dq=%22thief%20in%20my%20mouth%20to%20steal%20my%20brains.%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEwcDR1sraAhVQnFkKHXxOCFEQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22thief%20in%20my%20mouth%20to%20steal%20my%20brains.%22&f=false)*, a typical classical literature about the western genre/Manifest Destiny.

> "This is the real article. It is a double-rectified busthead from Madison County, aged in the keg. A little spoonful would do you a power of good."
>    "**I would not put a thief in my mouth to steal my brains**."

I would really appreciate you for answering my question whoever that is.

Comment: Please avoid excessive use of exclamations, huge fonts, and unnecessary drama. If your request is urgent,  this is the wrong site to visit. sometimes you can be lucky and get a good answer within an hour, sometimes you might have to wait a day or two.

Comment: "*Oh, that men should put an enemy in their mouths to steal away their brains!*" Othello Act 2, Scene 3 (Shakespeare)

Comment: [Link to Othello quote](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=othello&Act=2&Scene=3&Scope=scene&LineHighlight=1442#1442) It is Line 1445. _I remember a mass of things, but nothing distinctly; 
a quarrel, but nothing wherefore. O God, that men 
should put an enemy in their mouths to steal away 
their brains! that we should, with joy, pleasance ,
revel and applause, transform ourselves into beasts!_

Answer (score 5):

It means,

> I am against drinking and I myself don't (drink).

The idiom is from the temperance ([anti-drinking](http://www.teachushistory.org/Temperance/forstudents.htm)) movement. The idea is that alcohol is a thief that steals one's brains, so why stick the thief (alcohol) so near your brains (i.e., in your mouth).

Mary-Lou A reminds us that Shakespeare uses the phrase in [*Othello*](https://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=othello&Act=2&Scene=3&Scope=scene&LineHighlight=1442#1442). See [Good Reads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/504640-o-god-that-men-should-put-an-enemy-in-their).

---

Reference: [common usage](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22thief+in+my+mouth+to+steal+my+brains.%22)

Comment: I added a link to the Othello quote for you.

Answer (score 2):

The first speaker is offering the second some alcohol. The second speaker does not want to get drunk.

A quick search for the meaning of [**busthead**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/busthead) finds that it is US slang for cheap, home brewed liquor. The reference to a "keg" implies it’s whisky, so it is probably very strong.

The second speaker implies (using a metaphor) that being intoxicated would be like losing her brain and is not something she would willingly do.